# pattern matching in url and to use wget command to download multiple files

Tags: shell-script, wget

Say my links are:

```
https://www.horoscope.com/us/horoscopes/general/horoscope-archive.aspx?sign=1&laDate=20220101
https://www.horoscope.com/us/horoscopes/general/horoscope-archive.aspx?sign=1&laDate=20220102
..
https://www.horoscope.com/us/horoscopes/general/horoscope-archive.aspx?sign=1&laDate=20220201
..
https://www.horoscope.com/us/horoscopes/general/horoscope-archive.aspx?sign=1&laDate=20221201
```

However, I do not want to write a separate `wget` command for each date and month, I wish to download again and again.
Can someone help me in writing such a script?

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers form an integer interval, you could run something along the lines of

```
curl 'https://www.horo.....Date=[20220101-20220201]' -o 'hor#1.html'
```

Admitting Dates values to be formed by YYYY MM DD, in order to
get first semester of this year, one could write

```
curl 'https://www.horo.....Date=2022[01-06][01-31]' -o 'hor2022-#1#2.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

Write the dates in a text file like so:

```
20220101
20220102
20220103
```

And do a loop to read every line

```
for i in `cat yourtextfile`; do curl "https://www.horoscope.com/us/horoscopes/general/horoscope-archive.aspx?sign=1&laDate=$i"; done
```

Comment: This is not a very good approach since it requires a file for no reason (you could just do `for i in 2022{01..12}{01..31}; do` and ignore the few bad day/month combinations and it is reading a file in a way that is not recommended (never do `for i in $(cat file)`, always do `while read i; do ...; done < file` instead. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). You're also using the deprecated backtick syntax instead of `$(command)`.